# PriorityQueue<Integer> with lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, max-heap

Im trying to understand how lambda functions work with heaps in Java. the function below is to create a max heap

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> y - x);
```

Can someone tell me what `(x, y) -> y - x)` does?
Im told that "The lambda function will take two Integers as input parameters, subtract them from each other, and return the arithmetic result."

so if I do

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> y - x);
pq.add(9);

pq.add(5);

System.out.println(pq.peek());
```

Output is 9 since its a max heap but should I not get 4 as an output since (9-5=4)?

Answer (score 4):

`9-5=4` is the **priority** of `9`, and `pq.peek()` returns the **value**, **not the priority**

`new PriorityQueue<>(comparator);` uses `(x, y) -> y - x` to compare and determine which value should be next to be peeked.

So `9-5=4` is greater than `5-9=-4`

So the value `9` will be the first one.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to understand how lambda functions work with heaps in Java.

[Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) has nothing to do with [Heap Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), *per se*.

- Lambda Expression - is a language feature, acting like an *anonymous function*, which you can use/pass as a value;
- Heap - is a Data Structure, originally defined in Mathematics, and nowadays heavily used in the Computer Science domains.

---

> Can someone tell me what (x, y) -> y - x) does?

That is your *comparator*, to wit, a *lambda expression* which implements a `Comparator<T>`, and which you pass as an argument into your priority queue constructor.

`PriorityQueue<T>` then makes use of *that* comparator, and utilizes [`int compare(T o1, T o2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) method, each time you fetch (poll/peek) an element from it.

`PriorityQueue<T>` [relies on a contract, that](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)):

> int compare(T o1, T o2) Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So, in your code:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> y - x);
pq.add(9);
pq.add(5);
System.out.println(pq.peek());
```

Two numbers are *enqueued* in the Heap/PQ, and when you `.peek()`, `9` and `5` are passed into `x` and `y` respectively. As `9-5>0` true is returned.

---

> Output is 9 since its a max heap but should I not get 4 as an output since (9-5=4)?

`9-5=4` is only relevant for the comparator, to decide whether the comparison of two elements end up in 0, positive, or negative number, as already explained above.